# Is there any way to get Jar files of android library with all dependencies using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I am working on `Salesforce Chatbot` development for mobile applications. I have to develop it on `xamarin`(.Net). For that I need to have `.Net` libraries but those are doesn't seem to available.

Alternate way is to get `.jar` files of those Android libraries, add in `.Net` project and use it for development.

I am looking jar file for below configuration

```
   allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release'
            }
        }
    }

   implementation 'com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.3.2'
```

I found above information here [developer.salesforce.com/docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_android_app.htm). I am unable to download .jar files for above configuration on internet.

Than I tried to develop sample project using above libraries in `android studio` and get `.jar` files from it. I have made the project. I want to get `.jar` files.

I have two question now

1. How to download .jar files for above configuration from internet OR
2. How can I download .jar files from android studio from sample project I created

**Edit 1:**

Below screenshot of `ChatUIConfiguration` from `C# .dll`, there is no `create` method. While `create` there for Android `public static ChatUIConfiguration create`. `ChatUIConfiguration` has 278 lines of code  in android file and `C#` has only 100 lines. Am I missing any dependency or I need to add multiple jars from dependency folder?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating your sample project, you can get the `.aar` dependencies in Gradle based on this fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720958/2331445):

Add the following to the `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations {
    customConfig.extendsFrom implementation
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    from configurations.customConfig
    into "$project.rootDir/dependencies/"
}
```

Note the small addition regarding the `duplicatesStrategy` to avoid an error.

In Android Studio you can open the `.gradle` file, scroll to the `.copyLibs` task and click on the green arrow button on the left side.

This downloads the `.aar` files into a folder called `dependencies`. Among many others there is a file named `chat-ui-4.3.2.aar`.

Afterwards you can extract `.jar` files from `.aar`, just like described in this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485222/2331445).

**Manual Check**

Finally if you want to do it manually or check against the `.pom` file: you can download the `.pom` file from here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release/com/salesforce/service/chat-ui/4.3.2/chat-ui-4.3.2.pom

The other sub-dependencies are also listed there.

Comment: I am new to android studio. I am not very sure how to follow these steps. Can u please include first answer here as well. Also please let me know what path I need to keep here `"$project.rootDir/reports/libs/"`

Comment: @R15 probably easier if I show it in a short 50 second screencast, see https://www.software7.biz/so/iertzzaoeslkdjfoealskkdf/dependencies.mp4 (it took longer the first time because it actually downloaded packages).

Comment: It was helpful. I was able to get jar files.

Comment: Hi, one question, not related to this question :) . ChatUI.jar after converting into .dll file, I am not getting few methods, like `ChatUIConfiguration.create`, here `create` is not showing up. Here I am following this, if you have any idea https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_android_app.htm

Comment: In Android Studio one can see that ChatUIConfiguration (package com.salesforce.android.chat.ui) offers a static method `public static ChatUIConfiguration create(@NonNull ChatConfiguration chatConfiguration)`. This comes from `com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.3.2@aar`.

Comment: I have tried `chat-ui:4.3.2` and `chat-core-4.3.2` but seems some of code is being filtered not sure how. Could you please check edit1 in my question.

Comment: The information that this `create` method comes from `chat-ui:4.3.2@aar` is displayed in Android Studio if you use this method in a demo Java file and simply hover over it with the mouse. This information is reliable.