# Message origin must match parent origin! error JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error when loading `JavaScript` file to `Webview`.

```
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Message origin must match parent origin!", source: https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/eswFrame.min.js (7)
```

This is my JS file

```
<html>
<body>

    <button onclick="Chat1()">Submit</button>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function Chat1() {
            try {
                var initESW = function (gslbBaseURL) {
                    embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
                    embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'
                    embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
                    embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';
                    console.log("inside initESW- ", gslbBaseURL);
                    embedded_svc.init(
                        'https://ulr.my.salesforce.com',
                        'https:/ulr.force.com/visualforce',
                        gslbBaseURL,
                        '00D00055uj',
                        'US_Universities',
                        {
                            'baseLiveAgentContentURL': 'https://c.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                            'deploymentId': '5720Q008Oqg',
                            'buttonId': '5730Q000PID',
                            'baseLiveAgentURL': 'https://d.la3-c1cs-cdg.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                            'eswLiveAgentDevName': 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Q00000000jLUAQ_17d9a605e8e',
                            'isOfflineSupportEnabled': false
                        }
                    );
                };

                if (!window.embedded_svc) {

                    var s = document.createElement('script');
                    console.log("Control here1", s);
                    var MinFile = 'https://ulr.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js/'
                    console.log("Control here2")
                    s.src = MinFile;
                    s.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';                   
                    s.onload = function () {
                        initESW(null);
                    }
                    document.body.appendChild(s);
                }
                else {
                    initESW('https://service.force.com');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was, I was using `html` file from `Assets` folder and assigning content on `webview` but the data (html+JS) should come from URL and that should rendered on `webview`.